# Horizontally Align New Lines of Text After Image Has Ended

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I have an image on the right side of a line of text. If the text is long enough to wrap to the next line, it begins underneath the image. I want it to still start in the same spot horizontally underneath the first line of text instead.

Take a look at the last link on the right side under 'Warriors TV' for an example:
http://www.nba.com/warriors/fanzonelandingtest_009.html

Here is the code for those links:

```
<img style="padding-right: 10px;" src="imgsrc.jpg" /><a href="link.htm">Link Title Possibly New Line</a><br />
```

Anything I can do to make this happen? Let me know if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an inline `<img />` element, why not use the image as a background image and adjust the text padding?

```
#tab_warriorstv_links_fz span { 
    background:url("/warriors/photos/tvicon_fz.png") no-repeat left top; 
    padding-left:25px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, still seem to be having the same problem :( http://www.nba.com/warriors/fanzonelandingtest_001.html

Comment: Sorry Dougie, I looked too quickly at your HTML. My suggestions would be:

1. Remove the <br/> tags between the spans.
2. Apply the background-image and padding rules to the anchors instead of the spans.
3. Add display:block; to the anchors.

Comment: Ahh thanks, works perfectly now. I ended up changing 'left top' to '0px 3px' for a more precise look. Just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use an unordered list, and set custom bullets? That looks like exactly what you are going for to me.

Comment: Unfortunately superseding style sheets outside of my control make using lists very difficult, but this is exactly what I am trying to replicate.